# Appointment Booking Functionality using Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to build appointment booking functionality in sharepoint.

Scenario:

•   Two 1 hour meetings every Tuesday & Thursday

•   4 slots of 15 min each per meeting

Users can book a slot by specifying the Release, Date and the slot.

The booking form will ask for:
1.  Release

2. Available Dates
3. Available Slots

Release:
•   Data must be read from the master release table which has the start and the end date per release e.g.

Release Start Date    End Date

R51     1 July 2017   15 Aug 2017

•   Past releases must not be displayed i.e. if today is 16 Aug 2017, R51 must not be available for user to select.

Available Dates
Based on the selected release
•   Only Tuesday & Thursday falling between the release start and end date must be displayed
•   Past dates must not be displayed
E.g. - 
Considering today is 10th July and the release has started on 1st July, “Available Dates” drop down must not display 4th & 6th of July.

Available Slots:
Based on the selected release and date
•   Only the available slots must be displayed
•   Once a slot is booked it must not appear in this dropdown

Need to automate everything apart from providing the release information in the master table.
I tried creating three list

1. Release Information
2. Available Dates
3. Available Slots

I have a workflow which automatically calculates all the available dates and slots and update the above tables.

The only challenge is to display the filtered data on the User Booking form.

How can we achieve displaying the filtered values based on user selection in dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you're trying to achieve is known as a "cascading drop-down". If you search for that phrase (along with the word "SharePoint"), you'll turn up various JavaScript code samples, tutorials, etc., including [spservices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns), which is a well known helper library.

You should also be aware that Microsoft has created a product to handle this sort of appointment scheduling as well, called "[bookings](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/scheduling-and-booking-app)", and is available to Business Premium customers.

Comment: Hey Mike - Thank you for the suggestion and I do agree that this would have worked in case I had to deal only with Text columns.
CascadingDropdowns work only when we use Title columns of the lists which is defaulted to Single Line of Text data type. 
As I am dealing with dates I can't store dates in Title column and hence CasccadingDropdowns will not work for me.
Any other suggestion would be really helpful.